# Como possibilitar clique em toda célula de uma tabela abrindo arquivo em uma nova página

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando adaptar um código que deveria fazer o seguinte, ao clicar em uma célula de uma tabela acionar o link abrindo o arquivo em uma nova janela do navegador, o que tenho até o momento é isso, no `tr` da tabela um `data-url` que chama uma função.
O código funciona, mas não abre em uma nova janela

Tabela com a chamada da função:

```
<tr data-url="<?php echo $DadosFichas->Url; ?>">
  <td><?php echo $DadosFichas->Nome; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Função chamada:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('url'), target = "_blank" ;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Por quê não utiliza o próprio elemento `a` do HTML com o atributo `target="_blank"`?

Comment: o que acontece? abre na mesma aba? não abre?

Comment: Hm testou: window.open(url, '_blank'); Mas também queria saber o mesmo que o @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Olá, @AndersonCarlosWoss e Rafael Acioly, obrigado por perguntar, respondendo ao Anderson, preciso deixar disponível a opção de clicar em toda a célula e ao Rafael, a página abre mas na mesma aba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS (não necessário)

```
.tdClicavel {
   cursor: hand;
}
```

Script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#exemplo tr td').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.open(href,'_blank');
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

Tabela com id = exemplo

```
<table id="exemplo">
```

Célula clicável com classe = tdClicavel  (não necessário), porém obrigatório colocar a tag a conforme exemplificado

```
<td class="tdClicavel" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
 <a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest"></a> 

 ..............................
 .............................
  .........................</td>
```

No seu caso a td deve ser assim:

```
<td class="tdClicavel"><a href="<?php echo $DadosFichas->Url; ?>"></a><?php echo $DadosFichas->Nome; ?></td>
```

Comment: Olá @Leo Caracciolo, no meu caso não tenho o href.

Comment: me ensina essa mágica de clicar em algo sem url  abrir uma janela.

Comment: Acho que expressei muito mal, estou usando data-url no seu caso está pegando o attr href.

Comment: Obrigado @Leo Caracciolo, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: editei a resposta colocando exemplo de como deve ser a td para seu caso

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar a função `window.open()`, ficando da seguinte maneira;

```
$('td[data-url]').on('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o `data-url` no `td` ai invés do `tr`:

```
<tr>
  <td data-url="<?php echo $DadosFichas->Url; ?>"><?php echo $DadosFichas->Nome; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Use o `window.open` no lugar do `location` e coloque a tag `td` na frente da `tr`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tr td').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).data('url'), '_blank');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Olá @Wendel Rodrigues, fiz o teste aqui e não deu certo, valeu.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, fiz uns testes aqui e funcionou. Dê uma olhada ai.

Comment: Show, só preciso de mais uma dica, o que posso fazer quando tenho mais de uma url na mesma página? Acabe de perceber isso aqui.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta.

Comment: É que agora eu tenho menu com letras, tipo A B C que o usuário clica para chamar as fichas, para depois clicar na célula da tabela e abrir o arquivo em outra página.
Só que agora se o usuário escolher uma letra está abrindo uma aba nova

Comment: Você está dizendo que depois que adicioou esse código todos os links começaram a abrir em uma nova aba?
Esse menu você fez usando tabela também? Ainda não entendi rs

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: Pra você aplicar essa regra somente a uma tabela especifica, defina um id pra ela `<table id="dadosFicha">` e adicione no código `$('table#dadosFicha tr td').click(function() {`